# Policy route by source MAC address

Tags: linux, networking, ip, routing

I have a requirement to perform MAC based policy routing on embedded Linux platform (desktop Linux example will work as well) . I have examined the man of

***ip route add***

command and did not found any option to specify mac address as a policy criteria. Is any option to do that. May be routing based on some eatables classification results.

Thanks for advice,
Ilya.

Answer (score 0):

I've done reasonably complicated source-based routing years ago with the `ipfw` utility, on FreeBSD, though a quick check informs me that `ipfw` is deprecated now, replaced by `pfctl` (Packet Filter Control).  This is on MacOS/FreeBSD, but its likely ported to Linux.

Even many more years ago, we used to use the open source `GateD` open-source UNIX-based routing daemon for source-based policy routing on the NSFnet's backbone of IBM RS/6000s runing AIX, but that software package does not appear to be current.

Wikipedia has a list of open-source routing software packages [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open_source_routing_platforms) , most if not all will provide for source-based policy routing above and beyond basic `ipfw` or `pf.conf` provides.

Two packages that I've heard of before, though not personally used are [BIRD](http://bird.network.cz) and [Quagga](http://www.nongnu.org/quagga/).